# Microsoft Flow: How can I use the value from one field of Flow action into another for manipulation

Tags: power-automate

I am new to Microsoft Flow. I am creating my first flow which will start after user submits a form. Upon approval, it does some stuff and then needs to be added to outlook calendar as an all day event. Once done, it will send out an approval email to original requester.

I am stuck at "Create event (V2)" action which is used to add an event to Outlook calendar. I need to add it as an "All Day Event". There is a boolean flag to do this but it still requires me to specify the start and end time for this event. Now I can provide the start time as this is the date requested by user. I need to add 24 hours to this as end time so that I can create this as "All Day Event". This is where I am currently stuck.

[image: Flow Code and Action Image]

I have looked at Expressions where I can use `addHours()` function but I cannot find a way to use the value in "Start time" field in this function.
I have tried giving the same value for start and end time and enable all day event but it errors out. If I do not use all day event option, it adds the event at midnight for 15 minutes.

If I look at the json, below is what is represented.

```
 "Start": "@body('Get_response_details')?['r63544e49a58a41a9bab487bb684844ff']",
        "End": "@body('Get_response_details')?['r63544e49a58a41a9bab487bb684844ff']"
```

I need to find a way where I can take the time from one field and add 24 hours to it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer and it could not be simpler.
Once you click on the "Expressions" tab, you can use the functions provided by Microsoft. I am using `addHours()` function. When I need to add the arguments, I just switch back to "Dynamic Content" tab in the popup and click on the field that I need to use. Please see below screenshot.

[image: Microsoft Flow Image]

This resolves my current problem. But I still need to find out how can I reference any field from the action in an expression or in another field.

Answer (score 0):

User can not reference to another field from the same action because `The action cannot reference itself.`

However, we can `Initialize a variable` or use `Compose` action from "Data Operations" group and use this value in following actions.

Regarding start/end fields in `Create event` action - another shorthand function you 
can use to manually add hours is:
 `formatDateTime(triggerBody()?['date_field'],'yyyy-MM-ddT09:00')`